# Confused with Characteristic Function as Fourier Transform of Density Function

Tags: probability, fourier-transform, characteristic-functions

The characteristic function of a random variable $X$ is defined as the expectation of the function $e^{itX(\omega)}$ i.e.

$$\int e^{itX(x)}\rho(x)\,dx$$

where $\rho$ is the probability density. How is this the Fourier transform of the density function?

Comment: Shouldn't the exponent in the integral be $itx$?

Comment: @angryavian but definition of characteristic function uses expectation of $e^{itX(\omega)}$ where $X(\omega)$ is a function not the variable $x$ in my honest opinion

Comment: You either write $\int_{\Omega}e^{itX(\omega)}\,dP(\omega)$, or you write $\int_{\Bbb{R}}e^{itx}\,dP_X(x)$  ($=\int_{\Bbb{R}}e^{itx}\,\rho_X(x)\,dx$ if you assume $P_X$ has a density with respect to Lebesgue measure, as in your post); these two ways of writing are related by a change of variable from the $\Omega$ space to the real line.